How do I fix a "metadata credentials plugin" error?
Up until today, the query below (viz, { "customerId": "8109270380", "keywordSeed": { "keywords": [ "wheel loaders", "small wheel loaders" ] }, "keywordPlanNetwork": "GOOGLE_SEARCH", "language": "languageConstants/1000", "geoTargetConstants": [ "geoTargetConstants/20035" ] } worked flawlessly. Now today, without any code changes, but with a working OAuth2 flow, the code fails.
This invalid_grant thing is confusing. If I really did have an invalid_grant then I would not have reach this point in my code -- the earlier OAuth2 connection would have failed.
Has anyone seen anything like this before?
GoogleAds.DetailedRequestLogs Information: 1 : [2024-10-21 05:46:42Z] -
---------------BEGIN API CALL---------------

Request
-------

Method Name: /google.ads.googleads.v18.services.KeywordPlanIdeaService/GenerateKeywordIdeas
Host:
Headers: {
  "x-goog-api-client": "gl-dotnet/4.0.30319 gapic/21.1.0 gax/4.8.0 grpc/2.60.0 gccl/4.0.2 pb/3.25.0",
  "developer-token": "REDACTED",
  "login-customer-id": "7212153394",
  "x-goog-request-params": "customer_id=8109270380"
}

{ "customerId": "8109270380", "keywordSeed": { "keywords": [ "wheel loaders", "small wheel loaders" ] }, "keywordPlanNetwork": "GOOGLE_SEARCH", "language": "languageConstants/1000", "geoTargetConstants": [ "geoTargetConstants/20035" ] }

Response
--------
Headers: {}

Fault: Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="Unavailable", Detail="Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: Exception occurred in metadata credentials plugin. Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponseException: Error:"invalid_grant", Description:"Bad Request", Uri:""
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse.<FromHttpResponseAsync>d__51.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Requests.RequestExtensions.<PostFormAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows.AuthorizationCodeFlow.<FetchTokenAsync>d__44.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows.AuthorizationCodeFlow.<FetchTokenAsync>d__44.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows.AuthorizationCodeFlow.<RefreshTokenAsync>d__40.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.UserCredential.<RefreshTokenAsync>d__32.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.TokenRefreshManager.<RefreshTokenAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.TokenRefreshManager.<GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.UserCredential.<GetAccessTokenWithHeadersForRequestAsync>d__31.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Grpc.Auth.GoogleAuthInterceptors.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<<FromCredential>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Grpc.Core.Internal.NativeMetadataCredentialsPlugin.<GetMetadataAsync>d__12.MoveNext()", DebugException="Grpc.Core.Internal.CoreErrorDetailException: {"created":"@1729489599.069000000","description":"Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: Exception occurred in metadata credentials plugin. Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponseException: Error:"invalid_grant", Description:"Bad Request", Uri:""\r\n   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse.<FromHttpResponseAsync>d__51.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Requests.RequestExtensions.<PostFormAsync>d__3.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows.AuthorizationCodeFlow.<FetchTokenAsync>d__44.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows.AuthorizationCodeFlow.<FetchTokenAsync>d__44.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows.AuthorizationCodeFlow.<RefreshTokenAsync>d__40.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.UserCredential.<RefreshTokenAsync>d__32.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.TokenRefreshManager.<RefreshTokenAsync>d__12.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.TokenRefreshManager.<GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync>d__10.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.UserCredential.<GetAccessTokenWithHeadersForRequestAsync>d__31.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Grpc.Auth.GoogleAuthInterceptors.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<<FromCredential>b__0>d.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Grpc.Core.Internal.NativeMetadataCredentialsPlugin.<GetMetadataAsync>d__12.MoveNext()","file":"..\..\..\src\core\lib\security\credentials\plugin\plugin_credentials.cc","file_line":91,"grpc_status":14}") ---> Grpc.Core.Internal.CoreErrorDetailException: {"created":"@1729489599.069000000","description":"Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: Exception occurred in metadata credentials plugin. Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponseException: Error:"invalid_grant", Description:"Bad Request", Uri:""\r\n   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse.<FromHttpResponseAsync>d__51.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Requests.RequestExtensions.<PostFormAsync>d__3.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows.AuthorizationCodeFlow.<FetchTokenAsync>d__44.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows.AuthorizationCodeFlow.<FetchTokenAsync>d__44.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows.AuthorizationCodeFlow.<RefreshTokenAsync>d__40.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.UserCredential.<RefreshTokenAsync>d__32.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.TokenRefreshManager.<RefreshTokenAsync>d__12.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.TokenRefreshManager.<GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync>d__10.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.UserCredential.<GetAccessTokenWithHeadersForRequestAsync>d__31.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Grpc.Auth.GoogleAuthInterceptors.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<<FromCredential>b__0>d.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Grpc.Core.Internal.NativeMetadataCredentialsPlugin.<GetMetadataAsync>d__12.MoveNext()","file":"..\..\..\src\core\lib\security\credentials\plugin\plugin_credentials.cc","file_line":91,"grpc_status":14}
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
----------------END API CALL----------------

